# What is the best way to process arguments passed to main method in java?

Tags: java, process, arguments, program-entry-point

I wanted to know the best way to process arguments passed to the main method.
User pass the arguments from command line. i.e. I have a shell script which will invoke my java program. I am using this java program to invoke web service.

For Example,The format of the input is as follows
"Ram,ABC,XYZ,null,null,27-04-15"  "Raj,EFG,DEF,null,null,25-04-15" "Kiran,IJK,LMN,null,null,20-04-15"

as you see, within each string there are different attribute values(comma separated). and each set of input is space separated. And web service provides two methods which are as follows.

public void processArg(name,addr1,addr2,info1,info2,dob){
}

public void processArg2(name,addr1,addr2){
}

here first method processArg will be used to submit data for each set. Once this method returns success then i need invoke second method processArg2 which will check the status of the submission i.e whether it is success or not.

What is the best way to achieve this? Please let me know if i am not clearly explained.

Thanks

Comment: This is opinion based so I won't answer, but I can't see why, unless needed for some other purpose you're not saying, you'd store them. Without further explanation on what you're actually doing even separating the processing, as written, doesn't translate well.

Comment: Hi ,Actual requirement is to invoke web service which has two methods. first method is used  for submitting data and second method is to check the status i.e.whether submitted data is completed or not. Just to make it simple, i took this example for explanation. User will pass set of data from shell script . My requirement is to process input passed by user i.e. i need to process each set of data with first method  and then once first method is success,  i need invoke second method to check the status of the submission for each status. Please let me know if  I still fail to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string tokenizer to solve this issue.Following code can solve you problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        String dataString=args[i];
        String[] splittedData=dataString.trim().split(",");
        processArg(splittedData[0],splittedData[1],splittedData[2],splittedData[3],splittedData[4]);
        processArg2(splittedData[0],splittedData[1],splittedData[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2967784 if solutions resolved your query then you can close the question by accepting the answer